# AttributeError: module 'skimage.feature' has no attribute 'multiscale_basic_features'

Tags: scikit-image

everyone, anydody had the same problem?

AttributeError: module 'skimage.feature' has no attribute 'multiscale_basic_features'

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to update your scikit-image version, e.g. `pip install -U scikit-image` or `conda update scikit-image`.